# Can we schedule it (a call) for 15:30?

Tags: sentence-construction

I got an email with the following content:

> I'm available next Tuesday evening if that works for you.

And I want to reply with:

> Yes, can we schedule it for 15:30?

But I'm not sure if the sentence is correct.

Comment: What specifically are you not sure about?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, with 'it' used for 'the call', but if the necessary context if too far away in your conversation, why not simply say 'Yes, can we schedule *the call* for 15:30?'